# Wordpress Dispersing Multisites

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have plus 15 sites locked in a Wordpress multisite installation by a previous developer, the owner of the company decided that it would be in the best interests to break these up and segregate them to different servers. I am having issues trying to do this with plugin data not following.

Is there a better way to do this?

**My attempts so far are outlined like this.**

- I attempted to log in to one site and export it's XML then merge it and the theme into a new installation. This allowed the site to carry over, but I lost all the data for plugins and users.
- I dumped the entire database for the MU install, then tried to kern out all irrelevant tables and files. This achieved what I wanted, but left around a lot of bad table structures, and many files that aren't in use making it overly cluttered and slow.
- Recreate each site by hand. This also works, but adds weeks to creating each site individually.

My database structure weighs in at around 49.8mb and looks like this at the moment.

```
*DB: multisite  (200)

*Tables:
wp_13_posts
wp_ulc_2_commentmeta
wp_ulc_2_comments
wp_ulc_2_links
wp_ulc_2_options
wp_ulc_2_postmeta
wp_ulc_2_posts
wp_ulc_2_terms
wp_ulc_2_term_relationships
wp_ulc_2_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_3_commentmeta
wp_ulc_3_comments
wp_ulc_3_links
wp_ulc_3_options
wp_ulc_3_postmeta
wp_ulc_3_posts
wp_ulc_3_terms
wp_ulc_3_term_relationships
wp_ulc_3_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_4_commentmeta
wp_ulc_4_comments
wp_ulc_4_links
wp_ulc_4_options
wp_ulc_4_postmeta
wp_ulc_4_posts
wp_ulc_4_terms
wp_ulc_4_term_relationships
wp_ulc_4_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_6_commentmeta
wp_ulc_6_comments
wp_ulc_6_links
wp_ulc_6_options
wp_ulc_6_postmeta
wp_ulc_6_posts
wp_ulc_6_terms
wp_ulc_6_term_relationships
wp_ulc_6_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_7_commentmeta
wp_ulc_7_comments
wp_ulc_7_links
wp_ulc_7_options
wp_ulc_7_postmeta
wp_ulc_7_posts
wp_ulc_7_terms
wp_ulc_7_term_relationships
wp_ulc_7_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_8_commentmeta
wp_ulc_8_comments
wp_ulc_8_links
wp_ulc_8_options
wp_ulc_8_postmeta
wp_ulc_8_posts
wp_ulc_8_terms
wp_ulc_8_term_relationships
wp_ulc_8_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_9_commentmeta
wp_ulc_9_comments
wp_ulc_9_links
wp_ulc_9_options
wp_ulc_9_postmeta
wp_ulc_9_posts
wp_ulc_9_terms
wp_ulc_9_term_relationships
wp_ulc_9_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_10_commentmeta
wp_ulc_10_comments
wp_ulc_10_links
wp_ulc_10_options
wp_ulc_10_postmeta
wp_ulc_10_posts
wp_ulc_10_terms
wp_ulc_10_term_relationships
wp_ulc_10_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_11_commentmeta
wp_ulc_11_comments
wp_ulc_11_links
wp_ulc_11_options
wp_ulc_11_postmeta
wp_ulc_11_posts
wp_ulc_11_terms
wp_ulc_11_term_relationships
wp_ulc_11_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_13_commentmeta
wp_ulc_13_comments
wp_ulc_13_links
wp_ulc_13_options
wp_ulc_13_postmeta
wp_ulc_13_posts
wp_ulc_13_role_scope_rs
wp_ulc_13_terms
wp_ulc_13_term_relationships
wp_ulc_13_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_13_user2role2object_rs
wp_ulc_13_yarpp_keyword_cache
wp_ulc_13_yarpp_related_cache
wp_ulc_14_commentmeta
wp_ulc_14_comments
wp_ulc_14_links
wp_ulc_14_options
wp_ulc_14_postmeta
wp_ulc_14_posts
wp_ulc_14_terms
wp_ulc_14_term_relationships
wp_ulc_14_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_15_commentmeta
wp_ulc_15_comments
wp_ulc_15_links
wp_ulc_15_options
wp_ulc_15_postmeta
wp_ulc_15_posts
wp_ulc_15_terms
wp_ulc_15_term_relationships
wp_ulc_15_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_15_yarpp_keyword_cache
wp_ulc_15_yarpp_related_cache
wp_ulc_15   (4)
wp_ulc_16_commentmeta
wp_ulc_16_comments
wp_ulc_16_links
wp_ulc_16_options
wp_ulc_16_postmeta
wp_ulc_16_posts
wp_ulc_16_terms
wp_ulc_16_term_relationships
wp_ulc_16_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_17_commentmeta
wp_ulc_17_comments
wp_ulc_17_links
wp_ulc_17_options
wp_ulc_17_postmeta
wp_ulc_17_posts
wp_ulc_17_terms
wp_ulc_17_term_relationships
wp_ulc_17_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_18_commentmeta
wp_ulc_18_comments
wp_ulc_18_links
wp_ulc_18_options
wp_ulc_18_postmeta
wp_ulc_18_posts
wp_ulc_18_terms
wp_ulc_18_term_relationships
wp_ulc_18_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_19_commentmeta
wp_ulc_19_comments
wp_ulc_19_links
wp_ulc_19_options
wp_ulc_19_postmeta
wp_ulc_19_posts
wp_ulc_19_terms
wp_ulc_19_term_relationships
wp_ulc_19_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_20_commentmeta
wp_ulc_20_comments
wp_ulc_20_links
wp_ulc_20_options
wp_ulc_20_postmeta
wp_ulc_20_posts
wp_ulc_20_terms
wp_ulc_20_term_relationships
wp_ulc_20_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_21_commentmeta
wp_ulc_21_comments
wp_ulc_21_links
wp_ulc_21_options
wp_ulc_21_postmeta
wp_ulc_21_posts
wp_ulc_21_terms
wp_ulc_21_term_relationships
wp_ulc_21_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_22_commentmeta
wp_ulc_22_comments
wp_ulc_22_links
wp_ulc_22_options
wp_ulc_22_postmeta
wp_ulc_22_posts
wp_ulc_22_terms
wp_ulc_22_term_relationships
wp_ulc_22_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_blogs
wp_ulc_blog_versions
wp_ulc_commentmeta
wp_ulc_comments
wp_ulc_fb_friends
wp_ulc_fb_lastlogin
wp_ulc_groups_rs
wp_ulc_links
wp_ulc_options
wp_ulc_postmeta
wp_ulc_posts
wp_ulc_registration_log
wp_ulc_signups
wp_ulc_site
wp_ulc_sitemeta
wp_ulc_terms
wp_ulc_term_relationships
wp_ulc_term_taxonomy
wp_ulc_user2group_rs
wp_ulc_usermeta
wp_ulc_users
```

I'm curious if I remove **wp_ulc_** from the head of all tables (wp_13 being the exception),  and replace all instances of wp_ulc_ inside the tables, delete all tables except one site at a time, and load those on top of a fresh install if I will be able to keep plugin data and users? This is extremely confusing to untangle and I'm not sure the best way to proceed in separating each site from the MU install. Advice would be (extremely) appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, combine the best parts of #1 and #2. Import the previous site's XML/theme, and do a SQL INSERT for all data in your 'users'/'plugin' WordPress Tables.

There might also be already-developed tool to clean out old versions of posts and other WP content that are filling your databases.